# moving from mysql to a new server slashes showed up?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I moved an application I built years ago to a new server and now strangely on the text echoed in php i see something like

> "Randy Pausch\'s bestselling \"Last lecture\", with th...."

is it mysql or php to cause that? is something in php.ini I should disable/enable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like PHP [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are enabled on the new server. You should disable them, they are deprecated in PHP 5.3.